# can no longer add modules to my old python installation using pip only updates the new installation

Tags: python

I have 2 python installations in folders
python37-32 (This is the 64 bit python)
python64bit.

When I go into the python37-12 dir and do a pip install, it will install it in the python64bit folder

example
I just tried to install pandas_datareader in the python37-32 folder,
I went into the folder and rn pip
python37-32 pip pandas_datareader
My project still had pandas_datareader as undefined
when I tried to install it again,
I got
**Requirement already satisfied: pandas_datareader in c:\python64bit\lib\site-packages (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\python64bit\lib\site-packages (from pandas_datareader) (4.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.21 in c:\python64bit\lib\site-packages (from pandas_datareader) (0.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.3.0 in c:\python64bit\lib\site-packages (from pandas_datareader) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\python64bit\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.21->pandas_datareader) **

When I went into the python64bit folder and ran python
then typed from pandas_datareader import data
it ran fine.

How can I install modules in the 
python37-32 folder????

Comment: Instead of using `pip install`, use `python -m pip install`. That way, you can be sure that you are using the correct `pip` for that `python`.

Comment: When I chnage the name of python.exe to python2.exe your idear work. I dont know why if I run python, it loads it from another instalation

Comment: I don’t use Windows, so I can’t help you with configuring the path so that `python(.exe)` runs the expected version of Python. Using `python2.exe` sounds wrong since you are using 3.7 and 3.8.